# How do I write this circuit (returns 1 if the number of 1s in input is odd, otherwise returns 0) using a MUX?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

Here is the truth table:

[image]

The exercise is to write the SOP of this truth table using a multiplexer with 2 select lines and 4 inputs. I got the SOP expression:
$$(\lnot a\lnot b c)+(\lnot a b \lnot c) + (a \lnot b \lnot c) + (abc)$$

I assume that each expression in the parenthesis is one of those 4 inputs.

I understand how a multiplexer works I just don't understand exactly how I am supposed to apply it here. My professor wants us to use a 74151 chip. Here is the datasheet
[image]

I *think* I am only supposed to use one of those 2 outputs...

The question is: "Write the SOP expression so as to implement a multiplexer with 4 inputs and 2 selectors. Use the chip 74151 and NOT gates if necessary".

I don't understand the idea behind using a multiplexer here. Can someone explain? Thanks

Comment: Do you know what a "lookup table" is?

Comment: @Hearth No, what is it?

Comment: look it up.... ;)

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire That was a hint for what to look up.

Comment: Consider the rows of the truth table in pairs. Something is constant about each pair of rows, and something is not. Consider how you might exploit that. I hope you're prof allows an inverter or two as well as a mux :).

Comment: @vicatcu, you would need inverters only if you needed more than 3 input terms

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire, what is the output of the multiplexer if the input at the ABC pins is 001?

Comment: @jsotola Doesn't that depend on the value of the selector?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire, ABC is the selector ... if you mean value of the data input pin, then yes   ....  now imagine that some of the D0-D7 pins are tied high, and the rest are tied low

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely trivial to implement a 3-input Boolean function using an 8-to-1 mux because, literally, an 8-to-1 mux's function is, given three bits of "select" input, choose one of its eight data inputs. What is a truth table, if not that precise definition, using a mux whose data inputs are degenerately connected to HIGH and LOW values?

Here's a visual that might help, mapping a 2x1 mux schematic symbol to it's truth table.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFjp6Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But like I said, that is trivial. A more interesting question is, can you do the same thing with a smaller 4-to-1 MUX. Start with the truth table, and for a start consider the first two rows:

```
b2 b1 b0 v
0  0  0  0
0  0  1  1
```

When b2=0 and b1=0, v = b0... now map that to the behavior of a 4-to-1 multiplexer where b2 and b1 are your select bits. When b2 = 0 and b1 = 0, then multiplexer input 0 = b0. Carry on that reasoning for the subsequent three pairs of rows and you can implement any three input boolean function using a 4-to-1 mux, but you will, as I commented earlier, need access to an inverter and LOW and HIGH in many cases to pull this off.

A clever trick... you can use a similar reasoning to demonstrate for yourself that a 2x1 mux represents a universal gate, similar to NAND and NOR. The proof is left as an exercise to the reader.