# Combining MUX 4x1 to represent 5 variable function

Tags: logic-gates, multiplexer, boolean-algebra

I have the following function

> x’y’zw’v’ + x’yz’w’v’ + x’yzw’v’ + xy’z’w’v’ + xy’zw’v

I should implement it using **only** 4x1 MUX (more than one allowed, of course). I'm clueless on how could I combine 4x1 MUXes to handle 5 variables.

Comment: check out my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/468736/how-do-i-write-this-circuit-returns-1-if-the-number-of-1s-in-input-is-odd-othe/468753#468753

Comment: vicatcu answers your question. If xyzw represent the address of the MUX then each input is either 0,1,v or v' depending on the truth table.

Comment: If you know the concept of how to combine 2:1 to make 4:1 , you should know this too.

Comment: I've read the answer by vicatcu but I'm still struggling to conceptualize the problem with 5 variables. I mean, would you write the truth table of the expression complete or somehow would you break it into smaller pieces in order to be able to represent them with 4:1 MUXes that can afterwards be coupled together?

Comment: group the rows of the truth table into pairs... you will see a pattern in the input space where the last input is related to the output in one of those four ways,  and the other inputs are constant (0..15) iin each group. Right?

Comment: I got it folks! Thank you!